# Append data from Google Sheet API v4 does not work anymore

Tags: arrays, json, google-sheets, fetch, append

I am not able to append my data from the sheet since the google sheet api v4 update.
fetching works fine, but it gives and error when i try to append it with the json.feed.entry.
The code is as follows:

```
let sheetNumber = "Sheet1";
let sheetUrl = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${HanearkId}/values/${sheetNumber}/?alt=json&key=""
    
    fetch(sheetUrl)
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (json) {
        appendMenus(json.feed.entry);
      });
    
    /*
    Appends json data to the DOM
    */
    function appendMenus(menus) {
      let htmlTemplate = "";
      for (let menu of menus) {
        htmlTemplate += `
    
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="td1">${menu['gsx$nr.']['$t']}.</td>
              <td class="td2">${menu['gsx$bryggeri']['$t']}</td>
              <td class="td3">${menu['gsx$ølnavn']['$t']}</td>
              <td class="td4">${menu['gsx$ølkat.']['$t']}</td>
              <td class="td5">${menu['gsx$alk.']['$t']}</td>
              <td class="td6">${menu['gsx$beskrivelse']['$t']}</td>
              <td class="td7">${menu['gsx$pris']['$t']} kr</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
          `;
      }
      document.querySelector("#menus").innerHTML += htmlTemplate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this url, with sheet GID

```
let sheetUrl = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${HanearkId}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json&tq&gid=${sheetGID}`;
```

spreadsheet has to be shared